# How can we analytically know 34! equals to zero for the following C# code?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Hopefully my question below fits to this site. I think so!

### Background

Integer type (`int`) in C# takes 32 bit memory. Its value spans from `int.MinValue`=$-2^{31}$ to `int.MaxValue`=$2^{31}-1$. When a variable `int x=int.MaxValue;` is declared and initialized, incrementing it by 1 makes it equals to the  min value `x=int.MinValue`.

In other words, `int` wraps around in the interval given above.

### Question

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Factorial(34));
}
static int Factorial(int x) { return x == 0 ? 1 : x * Factorial(x - 1); }
```

How can we know analytically that 34 is the first value that makes `Factorial(34)` equals to zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the maximum power of $2$ which divides $n!$ is $$k=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac {n!}{2^r}\rfloor$$

The sum is finite (later terms are zero), so for $34!$ we have $k=17+8+4+2+1=32$ so that $34!$ is the first factorial divisible by $2^{32}$.

NB To see that it is the first, note that $34$ carries a factor of $2$, which gets us over the mark.